# Field calculator fails when computing First X coordinate in ArcGIS10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, coordinates

I have this line in python to compute First X coordinates into the Field Calculator from each polyline:

```
!Shape!.firstPoint.X
```

Then, when I inspected the attributes I see this rare thing:

[image: Example]

You may see that I have two fields (*StartX* and *InicioX*), both with the same Python code, one is a string field and the other a Float one. But **the computed VALUE is wrong**  :(

**You can clearly see that "spatially" the features are situated in different positions, but on its computed X Value are the same.**

**Could someone explain me that?**

Does anybody know any other way to compute this X,Y start and end coordinates from lines?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Remove the selection and repeat the operation.  It may simply be a case of the number of decimals being shown, which can be changed for the field

Comment: Removed selection, started a new ArcMap session, tried to export to a new shapefile... But nothing changes.

Comment: Is the issue that they are all the same value? Your question is a bit unclear

Comment: Have you run the Check Geometry or Repair Geometry tools?

Comment: As @nmpeterson suggested, there was something wrong with the geometry, just needed to repair. Thanks!

Comment: @nmpeterson Sounds like your comment was the solution.  Please consider including it as an answer so that it can be "accepted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing my comment as an answer:

It looks to me like there was an issue with the geometry of the shapefile, so running Repair Geometry should (and did) solve this problem.